# 2D Vector Declaration gives type-specification error

Tags: c++, vector

```cpp
struct vi2d { int x, y; }    
    
class Class
{    
private:
    vi2d nMapSize{ 10, 10 };
    
    std::vector< std::vector<int> > vTiles( 
        nMapSize.x * nMapSize.y, 
        std::vector<int>(4) 
    );
    
    // other stuff
}
```

I'm looking to define vTiles, a 2d vector of integers which is 100 x 4 in size.

I've seen that one can define a 2d vector with the syntax

```cpp
std::vector< std::vector<int> > vec(
    X_SIZE, 
    std::vector<int>(Y_SIZE)
);
```

I believe I've followed this syntax, but the compiler is giving me the following error:

```
error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'nMapSize'
```

Edited to be reproducible.

Comment: Please first extract a [mcve] and then provide the full commandline used for compiling and the output it generates. As new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Please paste the error message you get from the compiler as well. It's a vexing parse, use braces, i.e. `std::vector<std::vector<int>> vTiles{ ... };`

Comment: Edited. Is reproducible and includes the error message.